# How do I use Scala-Meta Parse an object?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scalameta

I am trying to use Scala Meta to write an annotation so I can generate another case class from an existing object.

But when I try to do this:

```
MyObject.parse[Source].show[Structure]
```

I got this error:

Error:(5, 20) not enough arguments for method parse: (implicit convert: scala.meta.common.Convert[domain.MyObject.type,scala.meta.inputs.Input], implicit parse: scala.meta.parsers.Parse[scala.meta.Source], implicit dialect: scala.meta.Dialect)scala.meta.parsers.Parsed[scala.meta.Source].
Unspecified value parameters convert, parse, dialect.
MyObject.parse[Source].show[Structure];}
                  ^

I am very confused because based on their tutorial, that's what I need to start with 
http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#.parse[T]

How can I reflect this object to loop through all properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse[Source]` parses text. You may try the following

```
import scala.meta._
"object MyObject".parse[Source].get.show[Syntax]
```

If you are creating annotation then it might look like:

```
@MyAnnotation
object MyObject
```

And in another module:

```
import scala.meta._
class MyAnnotation extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta { 
    defn.show[Syntax]
    defn
  }
}
```

Comment: I also tried to do .parse[Type], which doesn't work either. How can I use meta like reflection?

Comment: It seems that `scala.meta` is compile-time. I don't think it can be used like reflection at runtime.